# Erro ao gerar apk debug do Ionic

Tags: angularjs, apk, ionic

Estou gerando o apk com :

```
ionic build android
```

até ai tudo bem da BUILD SUCCESSFUL

e quando uso:

```
ionic emulate android
```

tambem da BUILD SUCCESSFUL

mais quando emula fica somente uma tela branca!

no:

```
ionic serve
```

ele roda sem problemas... oque pode ser ?

segue saida do emulate:
http://pastebin.com/MGH47r5P

Comment: Amigo o problema deve ser sua imagem do AVD do Android. Tente apagar o AVD em uso e criar outro se possível tente executar diretamente em um dispositivo físico.

Comment: testei em um S4 e um experia m2 e continua branco

Comment: Você está incluindo o `cordova.js` de forma correta?

Comment: sim é o criado dentro do assets/www certo ?